# The Director - Can you see what difficulty modifier you are at, and modify it?

Tags: left-4-dead-series

In Left4Dead, they say that the game runs an 'AI Director' that will make things harder if you are having too easy of a time, and make the game easier if you are having a hard time.

I would guess that 'Director modifier' is a value you could consult/change.

So is there a way to see the value of the 'Director difficulty' and is there a way to change it (like lock it to the easiest/hardest director or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest and most accessible modifier to change the 'attitude' of The Director is the difficulty option from the level select screen or the in-game pause menu. On higher difficulties The Director will spawn weapons and supplies less frequently and generally be less hospitable to the players/survivors.

To change individual values that the director controls you'll need to refer to the [console commands](https://left4dead.fandom.com/wiki/Console_commands) page to modify individual aspects of the game. This can include the rate that special infected spawn, the aggro range of a witch, limiting the availability of ammunition, or even disabling The Director entirely.

It is noteworthy that the console commands are only available on the PC version of Left 4 Dead. Console players will only be able to modify the difficulty from the menus explained above.

Comment: I always heard that the director is dynamic and is independent of what difficulty you choose when you select the level. Am I wrong?

Comment: Referring to the [wikia page for The Director](https://left4dead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Director) this is false. The director *is* influenced by what difficulty you set the game to be at.